# bnd gradle plugin fails after adding bundles to a repository

Tags: java, osgi, bnd

I'm working on an OSGi bundle using bndtools in Eclipse. I just added a new bundle (apache commons logging) to the `cnf/localrepo` repository, and our CI server is now failing the build:

```
[Gradle] - Launching build.
[workspace] $ gradle build
:mybundle  : Cannot find /error/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging;version=0 Not found in [bnd-cache, Release, Local, Bndtools Hub, /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myapp/workspace/cnf/nonosgi-repo r/w=true]
Error  : com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging;version=0 Not found in [bnd-cache, Release, Local, Bndtools Hub, /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myapp/workspace/cnf/nonosgi-repo r/w=true]
```

Project names lightly obfuscated just for simplicity.

It appears to me that the gradle plugin doesn't refresh the repository index - if one of my teammates updates from our vcs without refreshing in Eclipse, then they get the same error.

I know bndtools has the org.osgi.impl.bundle.repoindex.cli plugin, but I don't know enough about bndtools or gradle to apply it to my project. I also feel as though either (a) the gradle plugin should refresh the repositories on its own or (b) I'm using the repositories incorrectly.

Is it possible to add a task to our build.gradle that refreshes the indexes before a build?
Should we instead move all our dependencies to an online repository so bnd doesn't need to manage the indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should we instead move all our dependencies to an online repository so bnd doesn't need to manage the indexes?

Probably, but for various reasons it's easier in the short-term to continue to use our `LocalIndexedRepository`.

> Is it possible to add a task to our build.gradle that refreshes the indexes before a build?

bndtools' Bundle-Hub repository uses the org.osgi.impl.bundle.repoindex.cli plugin to reindex the repository in its [build.gradle](https://github.com/bndtools/bundle-hub/blob/master/build.gradle). Since I'm not fluent in groovy or gradle, I simply copied its code into *cnf/localrepo/build.gradle*:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
  repoindex
}

dependencies {
  repoindex group: 'biz.aQute.bnd', name: 'org.osgi.impl.bundle.repoindex.cli', version: '3.0.0' 
}

defaultTasks = [':index']

task('index') {
  /* Bundles to index. */
  def bundles = fileTree(projectDir) {
    include '**/*.jar'
    exclude '**/*-latest.jar'
    exclude '.*/'
  }
  doLast {
    javaexec {
      main = '-jar' // first arg must be the jar
      args configurations.repoindex.singleFile
      args '-n', 'Local' // REPO NAME HERE
      args bundles*.absolutePath
    }.assertNormalExitValue()
  }
}
```

Thanks to BJ Hargrave for pointing me in the direction of Bundle-Hub's scripts.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of repo is `cnf/localrepo`? If it is a [`FileRepo`](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/master/cnf/ext/repositories.bnd#L6), then you don't need an index. You just put the bundles in a folder/filename format for the bundle's bsn/version. If is is an [indexed repo](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/master/cnf/ext/repositories.bnd#L16), then you must maintain the index and commit it with the new bundles added to the repo. This is we manage the [bundle-hub repo](https://github.com/bndtools/bundle-hub/commit/6dffc30565f20a4c3012ef0f33722dc43026010d). Whenever a new bundle is added, we update the index.

As for the gradle plugin, you can write a task to reindex you repo each build. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/bndtools-users/index$20gradle/bndtools-users/OQ0Ns5v0ELo/JOB803lBBwAJ for a discussion about how to do this.

Comment: It's a LocalIndexedRepo. We used to commit the index, but we found the "increment" attribute in the <repositories> tag caused merge conflicts every time someone pulled from vcs.

A FileRepo isn't useful for us because we need to resolve runtime dependencies from our repository.

Comment: I saw the discussion on bndtools-users, but Eli's github repo no longer exists and I couldn't see the origin of his IndexRepository task type. However, I see now that Bndtools-Hub has a task (https://github.com/bndtools/bundle-hub/blob/master/build.gradle) which indexes its repository. That and a FixedIndexedRepo might help me.

Comment: The issue Eli had was running the reindex task and the build in the same gradle step. If you run as separate gradle invocations, you are fine. If you want to run in the same gradle invocation, then you need to handle clearing the errors after the reindex step as discussed in the group thread.